# how to shift a column in a 2d array java

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I got a task to take a 2d array of colors RGBColor and shift the image according to the input such as

`
(250,100,20) (250,100,20) (250,100,20) //would need to become

(0,0,0) (250,100,20) (250,100,20) // if the input was 1 but on N numbers
`

```
public void shiftCol(int offset ){
    int row = _image.length;
    int col = _image[0].length;
    RGBColor[][] shiftCol =  new RGBColor[row][col];
    if ( (Math.abs(offset) == (Math.abs(col)) ) ){
        _image = new RGBColor[row][col];
        for (int i=0 ; i< row; i++)
            for(int j=0 ; j< col ; j++)
                _image[i][j] = new RGBColor();
        return;
```

this is the code I've written for now, that just makes sure if the number of the offset given is equal to the number of pixels it becomes a black picture altogether. and another if statement that does nothing if the number given is above the number of pixels that are present in the array. would appreciate the help for the algorithm to shift the columns, and also the rows but not a must since it can be also implemented based on the above.